# Conjugation between commutative subalgebras of a matrix algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field and $M_n(K)$ the $K$-algebra of all matrices $n\times n$ over $K$. If $L$ and $M$ are two isomorphic commutative subalgebras of $M_n(K)$, it is true that there exists a regular matrix $S\in M_n(K)$ such that $SLS^{-1}=M$. That is, the isomorphism can be chosen to be inner?

Comment: Doesn't this answer the question (positively)? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%E2%80%93Noether_theorem

Comment: (Here $A=L$, $K=K$ and $B=M_n\left(K\right)$.)

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Dear darij grinberg thanks for your suggestion. But I think it can not be applied directly the Skolem–Noether theorem since the subalgebra $A$ is  not necessarily simple. -Miguel

Comment: Ah, right. I have forgotten that condition, sorry.

Comment: I assume you want L and M to be K-subalgebras. Otherwise you can consider Q(\pi) and Q(e) in C. 

Comment: Darji's example also fails if you assume they contain the scalar matrices. 

Comment: I've noticed that already. :)

Comment: Take $n=4$. Let $L$ be the diagonal matrices whose upper left $2\times 2$-block and whose lower right $2\times 2$-block are scalar multiples of identity matrices. Let $M$ be the diagonal matrices whose upper left $3\times 3$-block is a scalar multiple of the identity matrix.

Comment: If you aggree my answer, feel free to accept it.

Comment: An example was already given, but there are also examples with (commutative) semisimple algebras. Namely, in $4\times 4$ matrices, there are two non-conjugate isomorphic $K$-subalgebras isomorphic to $K\times K$, namely the subalgebras of diagonal matrices $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)$ satisfying $a_1=a_2=a_3$ on the one hand, and $(a_1,a_3)=(a_2,a_4)$ on the other hand.

Answer (score 11):

Two isomorphic subalgebra of $M_n(K)$ **do not need to be conjugated**. The following example is taken from Exercise 161 of my web site http://www.umpa.ens-lyon.fr/~serre/DPF/exobis.pdf

Set $n=p+q$ with $q>p>0$. Then define  $\mathcal A$ as the subset of $M_n(k)$ made of the matrices with block form
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0_p & 0_{p\times q} \\\\ A & 0_q \end{array}\right).$$
Likewise, ${\cal B}$ is made of the matrices
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0_q & 0_{q\times p} \\\\ B & 0_p \end{array}\right).$$
Both $\cal A$ and $\cal B$ are subalgebras of $M_n(k)$, with dimension $pq$ and the property that $MN=0_n$ for every two elements (of the same algebra). They are obviously isomorphic, because the algebra structure is trivial. But ${\cal A}$ and $\cal B$ are not conjugated in $M_n(k)$. However $\cal B$ is conjugated to ${\cal A}^T$ in $M_n(k)$.

Comment: Dead link is dead. (Also, exorbis.pdf doesn't work either.)

Comment: thank you Denis Serre.
  Your example responds to my question. Your answer made ​​me think of another question: two unital subalgebras (that is, containing the scalar matrices) are  conjugated?

Comment: Miguel, you could simply add the subspace $k\cdot I_n$ to each of the algebras - they would still be isomorphic but not conjugated. Also see my last comment for a different (diagonalizable) counterexample (which I hope to be correct).

Comment: @darij. Sorry, I completed the link.
