# Commuting nilpotent matrices and conjugation isomorphisms

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, ac.commutative-algebra, matrices

Trying to study isomorphism classes of certain commutative Artinian $\mathbb{C}$-algebras I was lead to the following problem about matrices.

Suppose you have a (non-zero) nilpotent matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$. Think of matrix algebras over the Artin algebra $\mathbb{C}[A]$. To be more specific, if another (linearly independent with $A$) nilpotent matrix $B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ which *commutes* with $A$ is given, I want to understand $\mathbb{C}[A]$-isomorphism classes of the subalgebra $\mathbb{C}[A,B]\subset M_n(\mathbb{C})$ of polynomial expressions in $A,\,B$. Clearly if $M\in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ *commutes* with $A$, the conjugated algebra $M(\mathbb{C}[A,B])M^{-1}=\mathbb{C}[A,MBM^{-1}]$ is $\mathbb{C}[A]$-isomorphic to the original one. Here's my question:

=============

If $\mathbb{C}[A,B]\simeq \mathbb{C}[A,B_1]$ as $\mathbb{C}[A]$-algebras, is it true that the isomorphism is induced by conjugation with a matrix $M\in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ which commutes with $A$? (so $B_1=MBM^{-1}$)

=============

I've been trying to work out an example to convince myself in the small case $n=4$. Assume $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$ In this case the general form of a - nilpotent - matrix $B$ which commutes with $A$ is $$B_{yxab}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & y & x & a\\
0 & 0 & 0 & b\\
0 & 0 & 0 & x\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix},$$ where $x,y,a,b$ are arbitrary complex numbers. As we are interested in the algebra $\mathbb{C}[A,B]$ we can simplify $B_{yxab}$ changing it with $B_{yxab}-xA-aA^2$ to get a new $$B_{yb}=\begin{pmatrix}0 & y & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & b\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$ Of course (almost all) the $B_{yb}$'s are conjugated as we can check looking at Jordan forms. However, the conjugation matrices $$\begin{pmatrix}by & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & b & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ do not commute with $A$ so the algebras are not $\mathbb{C}[A]$-isomorphic...

My question is related to [Conjugation between commutative subalgebras of a matrix algebra?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84591/conjugation-between-commutative-subalgebras-of-a-matrix-algebra), where one of the answers give a counter-example. However it seems that here I have more hypotheses (and more hope...)

Anyway, even if the answer for my question is NO I would appreciate any hint/reference to understand the previously mentioned isomorphism classes. Thanks.

Comment: What about $A=0$? Say, take $B_1^2=B_2^2=0$ such that $B_1$ and $B_2$ are not zero and not conjugate, then both $\mathbb C[A,B_1]=\mathbb C[B_1]$ and $\mathbb C[A,B_2]=\mathbb C[B_2]$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb C[x]/(x^2)$.

Comment: You are right. I'll edit to restrict to the case where $A,B$ are linearly independent...

Comment: You ask about $\mathbb C[A, B] \simeq \mathbb C[A, B_1]$ as $\mathbb C[A]$-algebras, but (because you conclude that $B$ and $B_1$ are conjugate by the centraliser of $A$) you seem actually to want to impose the stronger question that there is an isomorphism carrying $B$ to $B_1$.  Is that correct?

Comment: If I am not making a mistake somewhere, the answer is still negative. Simply split your space in two and let $A$ act only on one summand and non-conjugate $B_1$, $B_2$ only on another.

Comment: For example, let $n=6$, take a basis $e_1$, ..., $e_6$ and let $Ae_1=e_2$ and $Ae_i=0$ for $i>1$. Next, take $B_1$, $B_2$ as follows: $B_1e_3=e_4$, $B_1e_5=e_6$, $B_2e_3=e_4$ and all other $B_ie_j$ zero. Then both $\mathbb C[A,B_1]$ and $\mathbb C[A,B_2]$ are isomorphic to $C[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$ via isomorphisms under which $A$ corresponds to $x$. But $B_1$ and $B_2$ are not conjugate.

Comment: @LSpice You're right. The conclusion $B_1=MBM^{-1}$ is not part of the question and it was misleading. That was not what I meant. I appologize.

Comment: Your question can also be phrased as asking about the fiber over $(0,0)$ of Hilbert scheme of points $Hilb_n(\mathbb C^2)$. The Hilbert scheme is the moduli of colength $n$ ideals in $\mathbb C[x,y]$; when the underlying variety is the origin, this corresponds exactly to commutative nilpotent $\mathbb C$-algebras with two generators of dimension $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decided to turn my comment into an answer since it seems to be independent of the ambiguity noticed by @LSpice.

Take
$$
A=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix},
$$
$$
B_1=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
B_2=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then there are isomorphisms $\mathbb C[A,B_i]\cong\mathbb C[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$ carrying $A$ to $x$ and $B_i$ to $y$, $i=1,2$. But $B_1$ is not conjugate to $B_2$ (they both are in Jordan normal forms, which have different number of nonzero blocks).

Comment: My guess is that you could find that because the length of $\mathbb{C}[A,B_i]$ is too small with respect to the dimension of the space. Anyway this is not part of the question and I accept your answer, but I'd appreciate any hint/comments on my 'guess'.

Comment: @amateur Sorry I cannot quite get your point. All I can say is that of course any isomorphism between two finite-dimensional algebras can be made into conjugation with some matrix on a large enough space - namely the space the size of these algebras. And maybe in some circumstances you can do it more economically if you can find a common module of smaller dimension on which both algebras act. But I do not see any systematic method of finding such module in your situation.

Answer (score 3):

**Assuming that you are asking for an isomorphism taking $B$ to $B$':**

No. Take $A$ to be the $n\times n$ Jordan block with eigenvalue zero. The centralizer of $A$ is exactly $\mathbb C[A]$. Hence for any $B,B' \in \mathbb C[A]$, we have $\mathbb C[A,B] = \mathbb C[A] = \mathbb C[A,B']$. However, $B$ and $B'$ need not be conjugate: take $B = A^2, B' = A^3$. As long as $n \geq 4$, $\{1,A,A^2,A^3\}$ is linearly independent, and none are conjugate (since their kernels have different dimensions).

Comment: It's not quite clear what the question is, so this may not be an answer.  The question says:  "Are $\mathbb C[A, B]$ and $\mathbb C[A, B']$ isomorphic by conjugation by a matrix $M$ in $\mathrm C(A)$?", and in your case they are; but then the *statement* (no longer part of the question) goes on "so $M B M^{-1} = B'$", which, as you point out, is false.  I have [asked](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/365797/commuting-nilpotent-matrices-and-conjugation-isomorphisms#comment923688_365797) what the actual question is.

Comment: Note that the example in the post itself involves changing the choice of $B$ without affecting $\mathbb C[A, B]$, so it seems that the specific choice of $B$ is not important (and so it may, for example, be taken to be $0$ on "both sides" of your example).

Comment: @LSpice Indeed, I'll edit to reflect this ambiguity.

Comment: @JoshuaMundinger  I wanted a truly 2-generated algebra but that was not clear. As above, I appologize for the misleading comment (not part of the question).